# keyboardwillshow called twice even three times(vert) both on horizontal rotation and vertical

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I was trying to get keyboard measurements, but  during rotation process I always run into 2 notifications of keyboard measurement to horizontal position and three to vertical position in my print section.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(ChatLogMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true


   collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!,right: 0)
     view.addSubview(messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(48)]|", views: messageInputContainerView)
    setupInputComponents()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

}
deinit {
      print("Remove NotificationCenter Deinit")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
        print(keyboardFrame)
    }
}
```

Exactly what's going on: 
when i tap textField for the first time: there is only one string -Optional((0.0, 451.0, 375.0, 216.0)) - as expected.

Then when rotation process occurs : there is two strings Optional((0.0, 213.0, 667.0, 162.0))
Optional((0.0, 213.0, 667.0, 162.0))

And after all when I bring it back to vertical position: even three another strings shows up:  Optional((0.0, 667.0, 375.0, 0.0))
Optional((0.0, 667.0, 375.0, 0.0))
Optional((0.0, 451.0, 375.0, 216.0))

Somebody in other discussion said 'This is normal behavior as the keyboard goes down before it rotates and up again after the rotation' But I did not found any confirmation nor in docs and nor anywhere else. Why it does really happens?Please, I am really confused(

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by setting an `Int` to zero, then when the user pops the keyboard up, set the `Int` to 1 (or some other number) like so:

```
var keyBoardCount:Int = 0 
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if keyBoardCount == 0 { //If the keyboard hasnt been raised, raise it.
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
           let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            print(keyboardFrame)
            keyBoardCount = 1 //once you raise the keyboard, set the counter to 1
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the user accepts the inputted string (IE finishes editing the textField) set the `keyBoardCount` back to zero to reset the whole process.

By doing this you can prevent multiple firings of the function.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I know how can i cope with it, my question was about conceptual component of this issue

Comment: As you pointed out, the keyboard is lowered each time you rotate the screen. That means that the keyboard raise function is then called again to bring up the keyboard. Everything inside your `raiseKeyBoard` function will be called every time you rotate the screen. There isn't really any way to get around it or stop it from happening.